# Getting error when a method is made for post request

Tags: flurl

When made I post request is made its giving internal server. Is the implementation of Flurl is fine or I am doing something wrong.

```
try
{
    Models.PaymentPost paymentPost = new Models.PaymentPost();
    paymentPost.Parts = new Models.Parts();
    paymentPost.Parts.Specification = new Models.Specification();
    paymentPost.Parts.Specification.CharacteristicsValue = new List<Models.CharacteristicsValue>();
    paymentPost.Parts.Specification.CharacteristicsValue.Add(new Models.CharacteristicsValue { CharacteristicName = "Amount", Value = amount });
    paymentPost.Parts.Specification.CharacteristicsValue.Add(new Models.CharacteristicsValue { CharacteristicName = "AccountReference", Value = accountId });

    foreach (var item in extraParameters)
    {
        paymentPost.Parts.Specification.CharacteristicsValue.Add(new Models.CharacteristicsValue { 
        CharacteristicName = item.Key, Value = item.Value });
    }
    var paymentInJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paymentPost);
    var selfCareUrl = "http://svdt5kubmas01.safari/auth/processPaymentAPI/v1/processPayment";
    var fUrl = new Flurl.Url(selfCareUrl);
    fUrl.WithBasicAuth("***", "********");
    fUrl.WithHeader("X-Source-System", "POS");
    fUrl.WithHeader("X-Route-ID", "STKPush");
    fUrl.WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    fUrl.WithHeader("X-Correlation-ConversationID", "87646eaa-2605-405e-967c-56e8002b5");
    fUrl.WithHeader("X-Route-Timestamp", "150935");
    fUrl.WithHeader("X-Source-Operator", " ");
    var response = await clientFactory.Get(fUrl).Request().PostJsonAsync(paymentInJson).ReceiveJson<IEnumerable<IF.Models.PaymentPost>>();
    return response;
}
catch (FlurlHttpException ex)
{
    dynamic d = ex.GetResponseJsonAsync();
    //string s = ex.GetResponseStringAsync();
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this:

```
var paymentInJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paymentPost);
```

`PostJsonAsync` just takes a regular object and serializes it to JSON for you. Here you're effectively double-serializing it and the server is probably confused by that format.

You're also doing a lot of other things that Flurl can do for you, such as creating those Url and client objects explicitly. Although that's not causing errors, this is how Flurl is typically used:

```
var response = await selfCareUrl
    .WithBasicAuth(...)
    .WithHeader(...)
    ...
    .PostJsonAsync(paymentPost)
    .ReceiveJson<List<IF.Models.PaymentPost>>();
```